# how to do with_items with conditions

Tags: ansible

I would like to have possibility to group with_items statement with conditions. For exemple :

I have a task which stop docker containers on differents servers without conditions :

```
- name: "Stop all containers"
  docker_container:
    name: "{{ item.container }}"
    state: stopped
  delegate_to: "{{ item.owner }}"
  with_items:
  - { container: "efluidnet-{{ container_name }}",       owner: "{{ groups['efluidnet'][0] }}" }
  - { container: "efluid-{{ container_name }}-node_ws",  owner: "{{ groups['efluid-interface'][0] }}" }
  - { container: "efluid-{{ container_name }}-node_tp",  owner: "{{ groups['efluid-tp'][0] }}" }
```

And just next I have another task which stop another container but with conditions :

```
- name: "Stop container with conditions"
  docker_container:
    name: "{{ item.container }}"
    state: stopped
  delegate_to: "{{ item.owner }}"
  with_items:
  - { container: "ael-{{ container_name }}",             owner: "{{ groups['ael'][0] }}" }
  when: application_environement_type != "PARAM"
```

So now I would like to have possibility to merge these two tasks keeping conditions in my with_items statement.

I have not found a similar case elsewhere ..

Would someone have a solution?

Expected something like :

```
- name: "Stop all containers"
  docker_container:
    name: "{{ item.container }}"
    state: stopped
  delegate_to: "{{ item.owner }}"
  with_items:
  - { container: "efluidnet-{{ container_name }}",       owner: "{{ groups['efluidnet'][0] }}" }
  - { container: "efluid-{{ container_name }}-node_ws",  owner: "{{ groups['efluid-interface'][0] }}" }
  - { container: "efluid-{{ container_name }}-node_tp",  owner: "{{ groups['efluid-tp'][0] }}" }
  - { container: "ael-{{ container_name }}",             owner: "{{ groups['ael'][0] }}" when: application_environement_type != "PARAM" }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply create your list of containers conditionally and loop over the final list. Here is an example with tasks only. You can elaborate on that using a mix of inventory/ playbook vars declarations and tasks.

```
- name: Create my basic list of containers to stop
  set_fact:
    to_stop:
      - container: "efluidnet-{{ container_name }}"
        owner: "{{ groups['efluidnet'][0] }}"
      - container: "efluid-{{ container_name }}-node_ws"
        owner: "{{ groups['efluid-interface'][0] }}"
      - container: "efluid-{{ container_name }}-node_tp"
        owner: "{{ groups['efluid-tp'][0] }}"

- name: Add an other machine for relevant environment
  vars:
    additionnal_vms:
      - container: "ael-{{ container_name }}"
        owner: "{{ groups['ael'][0] }}"
  set_fact:
    to_stop: "{{ to_stop + additionnal_vms }}"
  when: application_environement_type != "PARAM"

- name: "Stop all containers"
  docker_container:
    name: "{{ item.container }}"
    state: stopped
  delegate_to: "{{ item.owner }}"
  with_items: "{{ to_stop }}"
```

Comment: Nice ! Thank for answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
- name: "Stop container with conditions"
  docker_container:
    name: "{{ item.container }}"
    state: stopped
  delegate_to: "{{ item.owner }}"
  with_items:
  - { container: "ael-{{ container_name }}",             owner: "{{ groups['ael'][0] }}", application_environement_type": "NOTPARAM" }
  - { container: "ael-{{ container_name }}",             owner: "{{ groups['ael'][0] }}", application_environement_type: "PARAM" }
  when: item.application_environement_type != "PARAM"
```

Comment: it work but my var "application_environement_type" is set in inventory file which i call when i launch the playbook. This variable is different depending my environement (production, integration...), i can't set its value here.

Comment: OK, I assumed you can set `application_environement_type` before firing the playbook.